# SQL. How to use ORDER BY clause while executing sp_executesql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic, sql-order-by

I need to use `ORDER BY` clause while executing `sp_executesql`.

I've tried following, but unsuccessfully:

**1.**

```
EXEC Sp_executesql @query + 'ORDER BY myChoice', N'@param1 TINYINT, @param2 NVARCHAR(60)', @param1, @param2
```

**2.**

```
EXEC Sp_executesql @query ORDER BY myChoice, N'@param1 TINYINT, @param2 NVARCHAR(60)', @param1, @param2
```

**3.**

```
EXEC Sp_executesql @query, N'@param1 TINYINT, @param2 NVARCHAR(60)', @param1, @param2 + 'ORDER BY myChoice'
```

Have you ideas? My syntax is incorrect.

Comment: Why not to include ORDER BY in your @query?

Comment: If your query syntax is correct (which we cannot know as you didn't provide it), try adding a space before the `ORDER` in your first try : `' ORDER BY...'`

Comment: in your @query add order by clause.

Comment: As others said if the syntax is correct you should be able to just use the ORDER BY.  For instance this following query works as it should.

`declare @param1 int = 1
declare @query nvarchar(max) = N'select * from seUser order by username'
exec sp_executesql @query, N'@param1 int', @param1`

The fact that you are appending the `@query + 'ORDER BY myChoice` and not getting results makes me think the query looks something like this in the end `SELECT * FROM tableORDER BY myChoice`.

Comment: there's a good chance you don't need to use dynamic sql at all... can you share the contents of your @Query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't apply [ORDER BY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx) to an SP, but you can capture the output and apply the ORDER BY to that. This sort of thing;

```
declare @results as table (col1 int, col2 int) 
insert into @results execute sp_executesql @query, N'@param1 tinyint, @param2 nvarchar(60)', @param1, @param2
select * from @results order by myChoice
```

You will obviously have to define the @results table variable to reflect your data structure.

Answer (score 5):

`sp_executesql` does not allow the statement being executed to be an expression.  It must be either a constant or a variable.  No concatenation allowed.

One workaround would be to create another variable to hold the concatenated string.

```
declare @query2 nvarchar(1000)

set @query2 = @query + N' order by mychoice'

execute sp_executesql @query2, ....
```